# core data fetch result not append to custom class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am fetching data from the coredata it is working fine but I am append coredata values to custom class, when show fetch data it showing like  this

```
  name Optional(Rahul Gandhi)desc Optional(Indian politician) profileimage Optional(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Rahul_Gandhi_%28headshot%29.jpg/37px-Rahul_Gandhi_%28headshot%29.jpg)
    name Optional(Rahul Raj)desc Optional(Indian composer) profileimage Optional(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Shiva_Temple%2C_Dhoni%2C_Palakkad.jpg/37px-Shiva_Temple%2C_Dhoni%2C_Palakkad.jpg)
```

but after append the core data to custom class  I'm showing that data in tableview but it showing empty

```
 class ModelData
{
    var name : String?
    var Description:String?
    var ProfileImage:String?
    init(name:String?,Desctiption:String,ProfileImage:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.Description = Desctiption
        self.ProfileImage = ProfileImage
    }

var modeldata = [ModelData]()

    func corefetch()
        {
            do{
                let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Val> = Val.fetchRequest()
                let Data = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                if Data.count > 0
                {
                    for actor in Data as [Val]
                    {
                        let nameval = actor.value(forKey: "title")
                        let profileImage = actor.value(forKey: "profile")
                        let descrption = actor.value(forKey: "desc")
                        print("name \(String(describing: nameval))desc \(String(describing: descrption)) profileimage \(String(describing: profileImage))")
                        self.modeldata.append(ModelData.init(name: nameval as? String, Desctiption: descrption as! String, ProfileImage: profileImage as! String))
                    }
                }

            }catch { print(error) }
        }
```

I tried many ways I did't find any solution how to append the coredata values to custom class

Comment: Show the line that defines context.  And what is Val?

Comment: @ElTomato when I append to string array it working y its now working custom class

Comment: val is entity with name, profile,desc as string

Comment: You are printing optionals. The output is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to save data

```
do {          
   try context.save()       
  } catch {       
   print("Failed saving")
}
```